# Query is too complex error in ms access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I tried to bind 3 queries into single query, using this code but when i click "Datasheet View" it showing error "QUERY IS TOO COMPLEX".

This is my code

```sql
SELECT 
    RPT_Invoice_Less.InvoiceNumber, 
    RPT_Invoice_Less.Terms, 
    RPT_Invoice_Less.Invoicedate, 
    RPT_Invoice_Less.OurQuote, 
    RPT_Invoice_Less.SalesPerson, 
    RPT_Customer.CustomerName, 
    RPT_Customer.CustomerId, 
    RPT_Customer.ContactPerson, 
    RPT_Customer.BillingAddress, 
    RPT_Customer.DeliveryAddress, 
    RPT_Invoice_Less.OrderNumber, 
    RPT_Invoice_Less.ShippingBy, 
    RPT_Invoice_Less.ShipReferenceNo, 
    RPT_Invoice_Less.Notes, 
    RPT_Invoice_Less.Price, 
    RPT_Invoice_Less.Discount, 
    RPT_Invoice_Less.Shipping, 
    RPT_Invoice_Less.Tax, 
    RPT_Invoice_Less.GrandTotal, 
    RPT_Company.CompanyName, 
    RPT_Company.CompanyId, 
    RPT_Company.RegistrationNumber, 
    RPT_Company.Address, 
    RPT_Company.MobileNumber, 
    RPT_Company.FaxNumber, 
    RPT_Company.CompanyEmail, 
    RPT_Company.CompanyWebsite, 
    RPT_Company.VatTinNumber
FROM 
    (RPT_Invoice_Less 
    INNER JOIN RPT_Customer 
        ON RPT_Invoice_Less.CustomerId=RPT_Customer.CustomerId) 
    INNER JOIN 
    RPT_Company 
        ON RPT_Invoice_Less.CompanyId=RPT_Company.CompanyId;
```

Comment: So...simplify your query.

Comment: What happens if you remove last two brackets?

Comment: Sounds about right for MS Access. I always ended up going back to the designer to get MS Access to produce the query and then modify from there. I admit that error message isn't very helpful

Comment: It usually helps me if I take the query text out and format it up in an editor (e.g. Notepad++).

Comment: Is any of the supplying data from other queries?  If so you may find that one of these is causing the problem.

Comment: Would down-voters explain their reasons, please?

Comment: How to simplify I need all columns, give me suggestions. @MikeW

Comment: It showing syntax error if i remove brackets @Alexander

Comment: yes that query getting data from table and another query @Westie

Comment: Try simplifying the query by optimising and testing the sub-queries, especially if you sub-queries have sub-queries. *The road to hell is paved with ... Microsoft Access*.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46732/discussion-between-sri-hari-and-westie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys finally I solved with your ideas and my current code i pasted below

`SELECT RPT_Invoice_Less.InvoiceNumber, RPT_Invoice_Less.Terms, RPT_Invoice_Less.Invoicedate, RPT_Invoice_Less.OurQuote, RPT_Invoice_Less.SalesPerson, 
RPT_Customer.CustomerName, RPT_Customer.CustomerId, RPT_Customer.ContactPerson, RPT_Customer_Address.BillingAddress, RPT_Customer_Address.DeliveryAddress, RPT_Invoice_Less.OrderNumber, RPT_Invoice_Less.ShippingBy, RPT_Invoice_Less.ShipReferenceNo, RPT_Invoice_Less.Notes, RPT_Invoice_Less.Price, RPT_Invoice_Less.Discount, RPT_Invoice_Less.Shipping, RPT_Invoice_Less.Tax, RPT_Invoice_Less.GrandTotal, 
RPT_Company.CompanyName, RPT_Company.CompanyId, RPT_Company.RegistrationNumber, RPT_Company_Address.Address, RPT_Company.MobileNumber, RPT_Company.FaxNumber, RPT_Company.CompanyEmail, RPT_Company.CompanyWebsite, RPT_Company.VatTinNumber`

`FROM (((RPT_Invoice_Less INNER JOIN RPT_Customer ON RPT_Invoice_Less.CustomerId = RPT_Customer.CustomerId) INNER JOIN RPT_Company ON RPT_Invoice_Less.CompanyId = RPT_Company.CompanyId) INNER JOIN RPT_Company_Address ON RPT_Invoice_Less.CompanyId = RPT_Company_Address.AddressId) INNER JOIN RPT_Customer_Address ON RPT_Invoice_Less.CustomerId = RPT_Customer_Address.CustomerId;`

This code working successfull.

Comment: That's excellent, Sri.  Becareful of your `INNER JOIN`s; if you have any missing (`NULL`) data in any of the linked tables you'll lose whole rows of information.  In cases where you have the potential for missing data use a `LEFT JOIN` (double click the table join in the query designer and select option 2: Include ALL records from '*table1*' and only those from '*table2*' where the joined fields are equal.

Comment: Actually I got that slightly wrong: if, when using `INNER JOIN`, you have a tables without rows matching your primary key the whole row will not be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the built in designer to reproduce as close as you can, if not replicate the query, I get the impression looking at that there maybe an issue around the `FROM` part of that query

Comment: Just speaking to Sri Hari now - it turns out that the whole thing is a big bunch of nested queries.